# Oracle 11g Create Function Fails

Tags: function, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a simple function in oracle for my lesson plan and cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ten_pct(num1 IN NUMBER) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
RETURN (num1 * 0.1);
END;
```

I've tried declaring a variable and setting it equal to the equation and returning it and get the same error.

Error(2,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:     . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache The symbol "" was ignored.

I'm hoping someone sees my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

That code works on my machine

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ten_pct(num1 IN NUMBER)
  2  RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5  RETURN (num1 * 0.1);
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.
```

Realistically, there is some difference between the code that you posted here and the code that you're actually trying to run.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a difference.  Your code also has ^K after the RETURN.  I'm assuming that is a typo?  I

Comment: I'm trying to show my students the difference between a stored function and procedure.  I have a function that takes 3 args, sums them, and returns the sum.  It works fine.  The code above says it creates the function but with the error I mentioned.  I didn't think it was a rights issue since I created another function.

Comment: @JayJarman - Yes, a ^K inadvertently got added when I cut and paste from my SQL*Plus session.  Fixed that.  If you are getting an error, the code that you are executing must be different from the code you posted.  As I showed, the code you posted works correctly.  Are you running it in SQL*Plus?  Or in some other tool?  Obviously, the code you posted doesn't take 3 arguments-- are you sure that you're getting an error with the code that you posted?